# Getting "name 'genrule' is not defined (did you mean 'rule'?)" error when using genrule in .bzl files

Tags: bazel

I can see everywhere in docs, SO questions, github, etc. that people are using `genrule` without any direct `load` statement, but when I try to use it in any `.bzl` file, I get the following error and I could not find out how to resolve this:

> name 'genrule' is not defined (did you mean 'rule'?)

I've tried calling it like this:

```
genrule(
    name = "hello20s",
    outs = ["hello20s.txt"],
    cmd_bash = "sleep 20 && echo 'hello20s' >$@",
)
```

and I tried to replace `cmd_bash` with `cmd` and had no luck either. I don't think it is a matter of how or with what arguments to call it, but more load or env issue. Any ideas?

I can add, that I'm able to run similar commands using `ctx.actions.run_shell` within the same `.bzl` file, so the only glitch I have so far is that it doesn't recognize `genrule` specifically.

$ bazel verson

> Bazelisk version: development

> Build label: 5.1.1

OS: macOS 12.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In macros defined in `.bzl` files, the "builtin" rules and function need to be referenced with the `native` prefix, eg `native.genrule`.

However, rules can't be called in the context of another rules implementation function, only mention this as you mention calling `ctx.actions.shell`